# imacros javascript remove double quotes

Tags: javascript, imacros

In this script everything works perfectly except the output is producing with double quotes.

when i run this .js JAVASCRIPT IN imacros firefox browser, it produces result as "facebook.com"
"blogspot.com".
but i expect result to be
facebook.com
blogpost.com

```
var jsLF="\n";
var ret=null;

var macro;
macro =  "CODE:";
macro += "VERSION BUILD=9002379" + jsLF; 
macro += "TAB T=1" + jsLF; 
macro += "TAB CLOSEALLOTHERS" + jsLF; 
macro += "TAG POS={{i}} TYPE=H2 ATTR=* EXTRACT=TXT" + jsLF;
macro += 'SET !EXTRACT EVAL("var text=\\"{{!EXTRACT}}\\";var text = text.replace(\'\\\\n\',\'\',\'g\');text;")' + "\n";
macro += "SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER=C:\\  FILE=hiprsites.txt" + jsLF;

var macro1;
macro1  =  "CODE:";
macro1 +=  "VERSION BUILD=9002379" + jsLF; 
macro1 +=  "TAB T=1" + jsLF; 
macro1 +=  "TAB CLOSEALLOTHERS" + jsLF; 
macro1 +=  "URL GOTO=http://www.alexa.com/topsites/countries;{{j}}/ID" + jsLF; 


//var text1_array=new Array();


//loop all the pages for each page get data
for (var j=0;j<20;j++)
{
iimDisplay(j);    
iimSet("j", j);
iimPlay(macro1);

//loop the current page and get all 25 result
for(var i=1;i<=25;i++)    
{
iimDisplay(i);    
iimSet("i", i);
iimPlay(macro);

/* text1_array[i]=iimGetLastExtract();
CSVString=text1_array[i];
WriteFile("C:\\hiprsites.txt",CSVString)
iimDisplay(CSVString); */
//iimDisplay(ret);
iimSet("i",i);
}
}
```

Comment: it is saving as this
"google.com"
"facebook.com"
"blogspot.com"
"youtube.com"
"yahoo.com"

i need it saved as this
google.com
facebook.com   
blogspot.com   
youtube.com   
yahoo.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is how saveas command works with txt files, the thing you can do is to change your output file from txt to csv and you won't see the quotes